# Meaning of 形の上では前後だけど、気持ちとしては

Tags: meaning

> > 最後の戦い。
> >     マリウスが倒れ、アンジョルラスが駆け寄る。嘆く彼の手をグランテールが握りしめ、アンジョルラスはその肩を抱き寄せ、それからバリケードを駆け上がっていく。アンジョルラスが先で、グランテールがあとからついていく形。**形の上では前後だけど、気持ちとしては**、グランテールもアンジョルラスと一緒に駆け上っていたと思う。

This is from a recap of a scene in the musical of Les Miserables. From a video of the scene I saw, there's a giant barricade on stage where the characters are on top and firing at the enemies. Marius gets shot and falls from the barricade, Enjolras rushes to him but then goes back up the barricade. After he gets shot, Grantaire goes up the barricade to die and gets shot too.
The problem is that in this part of the recap: グランテールもアンジョルラスと一緒に駆け上っていたと思う the author of the blog is saying something about Grantaire running up the barricade together (at the same time) with Enjolras, which is not the case (he went after).

My interpretation of this sentence is that 形 is describing the way how things are happening objectively(like in:"the way things went about is A did this and B this" to describe something you saw on TV for example) and 形の上では would be 'From the perspective of the situation', but I can't figure out 前後 in this context.
For 気持ちとしては I found this definition:

> “自分の本心を話すときに前置きとして使う表現。多くの場合、願望の表現である”

So, does that last part means: "would've been great if Grantaire would've run up the barricade with Enjolras"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous sentence says:

> アンジョルラスが先で、グランテールがあとからついていく**形**

The 形 is Enjolras in the front and Grantaire in the back.

The 形 in your sentence then refers to that and so 前後 is referring to the front and rear (Enjolras and Grantaire respectively).

So then 形の上では前後だけど means something like:

> They are front and back in terms of formation but...

気持ちとしては is really contrasting 気持ち with the 形 mentioned previously. In particular, it talks about how they are 一緒 in 気持ち instead of 前後 in 形.

So the part you're interested in means something like:

> I think that although they are running one behind another in formation, in their feelings they are running upwards together.